# How to format a phone number using PhoneNumberUtils?

Tags: android

How can I format a phone number using [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html)?

E.g.: `1234567890` → `(123) 456-7890`

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55416434/7041761

Answer (score 86, accepted):

At its most basic:

```
String formattedNumber = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(unformattedNumber);
```

This will automatically format the number according to the rules for the country the number is from.

You can also format Editable text in-place using:

```
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(Editable text, int defaultFormattingType);
```

Take a look at [`PhoneNumberUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) for more options.

Comment: instead of 1234567890 → (123) 456-7890 I'm getting:

Comment: While the answer is correct I think the actually correct answer for this question is that the formatting is NOT customizable enough unless you want to write your own implementation. :-(  STPhoneFormatter in CocoaPods for iOS development is a pretty slick library to handle this over there.  No such joy for Android. :-/

Comment: @Sven Viking i want to formatted number convert in unformstted number like.. `555-4 to 5554` any solution..?

Comment: [PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(String source)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNumber(java.lang.String)) is deprecated in Lollipop, one need to use [PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber (String phoneNumber, String defaultCountryIso)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html#formatNumber(java.lang.String,java.lang.String))

Comment: `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(Editable text, int defaultFormattingType);` What is `defaultFormattingType` here ?

Comment: This method available from api 21, how can i format a number in US below 21 ?.

Comment: Ohh the same method is working on 19 also, i wondered why it is working?

Answer (score 30):

I opted to use google's version (https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) because then the min SDK can be lower (I think it isn't in Android SDK until 21).

Use is something like this:

```
PhoneNumberUtil pnu = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
Phonenumber.PhoneNumber pn = pnu.parse("1234567890", "US");
String pnE164 = pnu.format(pn, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
```

In Android Studio one need add this to dependencies in build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    ...
    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.2'
}
```

Answer (score 25):

formatNumber got deprecated on LOLLIPOP, after that you need to add the locale as an extra argument.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  return PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(yourStringPhone,Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
} else {
//Deprecated method
  return PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(yourStringPhone); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this but phone number doesn't get formatted on mobile device where as it's working properly on tablet, tablet shows formatted number.

Comment: I am in India and Locale.getDefault().getCountry() gives me "US". Ok, that's not an issue but number does not gets formatted. It returns 10/11 digit number as is. And with deprecated method, it returns formatted.

Comment: getCountry() returns "" for me

Comment: Worked in USA for me.

Answer (score 8):

It looks like [this library from Google](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) might be a better solution for doing customized formatting in Android.

API docs: 
https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 6):

**2020- November**

Following worked for me for all version of OS:

```
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(yourStringPhone,Locale.getDefault().getCountry());
```

Comment: change language and try to call this method again

Answer (score 1):

Standalone solution for format raw phone number, if you don`t know your country and need support on pre-lollipop.

```
fun formatNumberCompat(rawPhone: String?, countryIso: String = ""): String {
    if (rawPhone == null) return ""

    var countryName = countryIso
    if (countryName.isBlank()) {
        countryName = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Resources.getSystem().configuration.locales[0].country
        } else {
            Resources.getSystem().configuration.locale.country
        }
    }

    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(rawPhone)
    } else {
        PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(rawPhone, countryName)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the need to check about LOLLIPOP ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34521644/using-phonenumberutils-formatnumber-on-api-16

Comment: please, read docs. 
Constructor of PhoneUtils with 2 args, supported only after lollipop.

Answer (score 1):

In order to define your custom formatting pattern, you have to use `formatByPattern` method with your instance of `Phonemetadata.NumberFormat`

```kotlin
        private fun getFormattedNumber(numberString: String): String? {
        val phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance()
        val numberFormat = Phonemetadata.NumberFormat().apply {
            pattern = "(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d+)"
            format = "($1) $2-$3"//your custom formatting
        }
        try {
            val phoneNumberPN: Phonenumber.PhoneNumber =
                phoneNumberUtil.parse(numberString, Locale.US.country)
            
            return phoneNumberUtil.formatByPattern(
                phoneNumberPN,
                PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL,
                listOf(numberFormat)
            )//returns the expected result
        } catch (e: NumberParseException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
```

Answer (score 0):

2020 working sulotion:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String countryIso = telephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso().toUpperCase();              //important!!

phoneNumberTextView.setText(PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber("3473214567", countryIso));
```

Answer (score 0):

We can easily do this by:

```
val tm = act.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager?
val formattedPhoneNumber= PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phone, tm?.simCountryIso?.toUpperCase())
```

here, `tm?.simCountryIso?.toUpperCase()` returns iso code, "in" in my case and we used `toUpperCase()` to convert it into "IN"

you can also use networkCountryIso instead of simCountryIso.

From [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager):

**getNetworkCountryIso():** Returns the ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 country code equivalent of the MCC (Mobile Country Code) of the current registered operator or the cell nearby, if available.

**getSimCountryIso():** Returns the ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 country code equivalent for the SIM provider's country code.

you can also pass direct iso code, for example:

```
PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber("2025550739", "US") // output: (202) 555-0739
```

Check the [list](http://kirste.userpage.fu-berlin.de/diverse/doc/ISO_3166.html) of iso codes.