# Formatting Phone Number in Android

Tags: android, phone-number

I tried the following code to format phone number in android:-

```
public static String formatPhoneNumber(String number){

        return PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(number);
    }
```

I am passing "19253951646" to the function..
It returns the text in the format 1-925-395-1646.
I want the result in the format 1(925)395-1646.
Any help would be highly apprciated.

Comment: First Sreekant you have not added  any code which u r referring in question. Second can you tell what way u r passing the number to `PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(number);` some sample of `number` passed in method

Comment: @BlackDevil..Please see the edits.

Comment: Have you looked on this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106859/how-to-format-a-phone-number-using-phonenumberutils

Comment: Black Devil... Well,I tried that link already... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrote my own function to format the number.

```
public static String formatPhoneNumber(String number){  
        number  =   number.substring(0, number.length()-4) + "-" + number.substring(number.length()-4, number.length());
        number  =   number.substring(0,number.length()-8)+")"+number.substring(number.length()-8,number.length());
        number  =   number.substring(0, number.length()-12)+"("+number.substring(number.length()-12, number.length());
        return number;
    }
```

Comment: Great answer, I tweaked this solution and it worked for me.

Comment: @KingOfTheJungle but this doesn't format as you type it right? it will directly change the format once at the end ?

Answer (score 2):

This is my code and this run without error:

```
    mobile.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            StringBuilder digits = new StringBuilder();
            StringBuilder phone = new StringBuilder();
            char[] chars = mobile.getText().toString().toCharArray();


            for (int x = 0; x < chars.length; x++) {
                if (Character.isDigit(chars[x])) {
                    digits.append(chars[x]);
                }
            }

            //Format for 6 digits and below
            if (digits.toString().length() >= 6) {
                String six = new String();
                six += digits.toString();
                phone.append(six);
                //Format for 7 digits 
                if (digits.toString().length() >= 7) {
                    phone.setLength(0);
                    String countryCode = new String();
                    countryCode += digits.toString().substring(0, 3) + "-";
                    countryCode += digits.toString().substring(3,7);

                    phone.append(countryCode);
                    //Format for 8 and 9 digits
                    if (digits.toString().length() >= 8) {
                        phone.setLength(0);
                        String eight = new String();
                        eight += digits.toString();
                        phone.append(eight);
                        //Format for 10 digits
                        if (digits.toString().length() >= 10) {
                            phone.setLength(0);

                            String regionCode = new String();

                            regionCode += "(" + digits.toString().substring(0, 3) + ") ";
                            regionCode += digits.toString().substring(3, 6) + "-";

                            phone.append(regionCode);
                            //Format for 11 digits
                            if (digits.toString().length() >= 11) {
                                String code = new String();
                                phone.setLength(0);
                                code += digits.toString().substring(0, 1);
                                code += "(" + digits.toString().substring(1, 4) + ")- ";
                                code += digits.toString().substring(4, 7) + "-";
                                code += digits.toString().substring(7, 11);
                                phone.append(code);
                                //Format for 12 digits
                                if (digits.toString().length() >= 12) {
                                    String newCode = new String();
                                    phone.setLength(0);
                                    newCode += "+" + digits.toString().substring(0, 2);
                                    newCode += "(" + digits.toString().substring(2, 5) + ")";
                                    newCode += digits.toString().substring(5, 8) + "-";
                                    newCode += digits.toString().substring(8, 12);

                                    phone.append(newCode);
                                    //Format for 12 digits and more
                                    if (digits.toString().length() >= 13) {
                                        String noMoreThanTwelve = new String();
                                        phone.setLength(0);
                                        noMoreThanTwelve += digits.toString();
                                        phone.append(noMoreThanTwelve);
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                phone.append(digits.toString().substring(6));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                mobile.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                mobile.setText(phone.toString());
                mobile.setSelection(mobile.getText().toString().length());
                mobile.addTextChangedListener(this);
            } else {
                return;
            }

        }
    });
```

This is the output of my code:

Below 7 digits:
123456 = 123456

7 Digits:
1234567 = 123-4567

8 Digits
12345678 = 12345678

9 Digits
123456789 = 123456789

10 Digits
1234567890 = (123) 456-7890

11 Digits
12345678901 = 1 (234) 567-8901

12 Digits
123456789012 = +12 (345) 678-9012

More than 12 Digits
12345678901234 ....

Sorry for using these variables but I do hope you understand my code.

Answer (score 0):

Android SDKs [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html) has more or less adequate phone number formatting utils but sometimes it might not be enough for special needs.

Try out alternative library [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) described as "Google's common Java, C++ and JavaScript library for parsing, formatting, storing and validating international phone numbers. The Java version is optimized for running on smartphones, and is used by the Android framework since 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich)."

The library has different phone number formatting options.

Answer (score -5):

1-925-395-1646

number have international USA format. If you want custom format, you can parse number manually and format him.

So, you can try insert +1 before number.

A proof on my iPhone:

[image]

Also try that: [How to format a phone number using PhoneNumberUtils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106859/how-to-format-a-phone-number-using-phonenumberutils)

Comment: Not Clear...I want the thing to be done in the native way...Any clue how to do that?

Comment: As I had anticipated it doesn't work..what I get is +1-925-395-1646.

Comment: I am talking about android here...why have you put an iPhone Image?

Comment: I can write a function myself...But it is better if we use the native code.I prefer to do it native way if possible.

Comment: read updated post. Second parameter of PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber. Check API, please

Comment: int defaultFormattingType - what is it? :-) proof link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

Comment: so, than replace string first "-" and second "-" to "(" and ")", but you need check a length of number or quantity of "-" in nubmer.... more ways I don `t know :)))

Comment: thankful that Google even brought this feature. I tried to implement it in php and I got nothing nothing normal

Comment: invent your phone, your sdk and your best in the world api!

Comment: or using iPhone for your application :-P

Comment: Display numbers doesn't have rules, they depend on the locale. For example, read about display number in Germany :-D