# How to do number parsing?

Tags: android, libphonenumber

I am making a project in which i am using the phone contacts . In this app i am matching the number( incoming call number) with the numbers saved in contact list. I have formated the number and it is working over the phones on which the number is saved with this format +919045308261 and its not working over the phones on which the number is saved with this format +91 90 45 308261 
The code that I have used is...

```
int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));

                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {


                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[] { contact_id }, null);

                    while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {


                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                                .getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                        String formatedphn = PhoneNumberUtils.formatNumber(phoneNumber);
formatedphn = formatedphn.trim();
                        Log.i("formated number: ", formatedphn);
                //here the number is from which the call is incoming        
                        if(number.equals(formatedphn)){
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got it", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.i("Match occurs", "got a hit");
                            //Log.i("number= ", number);
                            String contname = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(DISPLAY_NAME));
                            if(!contname.equals(null)){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                tts.speak(contname+" calling", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                            }
                        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) removes all leading and trailing spaces of a String, but not those in the middle.
To remove all whitespaces of a String you can use this regex:

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Comment: thanks it worked but could you please solve 1 more problem of mine, in different phone you know that the number +919045308261 is saved in diffrent ways like 0 90 45 308261, 9045308261,90 45 308261.
How may i match these with +919045308261 from which the call is incoming

Comment: This I don't know. Consider to open a new question to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following thing, compare after removing all the white spaces from the string.

```
String st = " Hello world";
st = st.trim(); // It should work fine and remove all white spaces.
```

now compare two strings as you are comparing.
All d best

Comment: I did that thing also but its not working now also . I have done updation in my code...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some references:

- [using Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5959341/2219600)
- Check [PhoneNumberUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html), this will have the function to format.

Answer (score 0):

According to This Thread [How to format a phone number using PhoneNumberUtils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106859/how-to-format-a-phone-number-using-phonenumberutils)
you can get formatted Number from +98 91 28 033921 to this 0912 80 33921 and compare with this