# Formatting phone number to match

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new to android development. I am trying to make an SMS app. Everything works fine already except for phone number formatting. Say for example, I live in the Philippines and I got 2 different SMS from the same number.

> First SMS address: +639123456789
>
> Second SMS address: 09123456789
>
> **+639123456789** must equal to **09123456789**
>
> Or Swiss number **+41446681800** must equal to **0446681800**

Now how can I format either of these addresses that they will match. String manipulation will work but it's limited for Philippines only. I found this **libphonenumber** but I have no idea how to use it on my current project. Sorry for being noob. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the PhoneNumberUtils class? It has a lot of methods that you might find helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106859/how-to-format-a-phone-number-using-phonenumberutils

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/01/android-libphonenumber-example.html) you can find an example for [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) lib.

Using this library you can convert those numbers into international format, after you can match the numbers and if you want, you can get the country code too.

```
internationalFormatMobileNumber = phoneUtil.format(yourNumber, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the country for which you want to do it, you can use Google's open source library https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber  . Here is how you can format it:

---

```
             String numberStr = "8885551234"
            PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
            try {
              PhoneNumber numberProto = phoneUtil.parse(numberStr, "US");
              //Since you know the country you can format it as follows:
              System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(numberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL));
            } catch (NumberParseException e) {
              System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
            }
```