# how to add hyphen (-) to phone number after 2 digit ,7 digits using addTextChangedListener() in Android

Tags: android, addtextchangedlistener

I am using `editText` with `addTextChangedListener()` how to format and achieve the pattern what I am looking for.
It should work while adding and deleting also example on character length is 2 hyphen should be added and when I delete and add again its should be added again.

Comment: what format number you want to do. see this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106859/how-to-format-a-phone-number-using-phonenumberutils

Answer (score 0):

Please check it.

```
txt_HomeNo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        txt_HomeNo.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                    keyDel = 1;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (keyDel == 0) {
            int len = txt_HomeNo.getText().length();
            if(len == 3) {
                txt_HomeNo.setText(txt_HomeNo.getText() + "-");
                txt_HomeNo.setSelection(txt_HomeNo.getText().length());
            }
        } else {
            keyDel = 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Comment: tried above solution there is some problem with code keyDel should be int variable? adding its working fine but deleting and adding its again not giving hpyepn on excepted length of character

Comment: same code used as above pasted along with this line     private int keyDel = 0;

Comment: tried above solution there is some problem with code keyDel should be int variable? adding its working fine but deleting and adding its again not giving hpyepn on excepted length of character

Comment: example I have taken hypen at 2,7 when I add number as 95-35 when I delete 3 and 5 and when I m again inputing number hypen is not appending and its getting happened at 7 element as 9535536-

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own custom filters to `EditText`

---

This example of the filter adds "-" after you type 2 characters

```
 InputFilter [] phoneFilter = new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter() {
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        if (end > start ){
            String resultingTxt = dest.toString().substring(0, dstart) + source.subSequence(start, end) + dest.toString().substring(dend);
            if (resultingTxt.length() == 2)
                return source.subSequence(start, end) + "-";
        }

        return null;
    }
}};
editText.setFilters(phoneFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use some predefined TextChange watcher [PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html)

```
EditText inputField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputfield);
inputField.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

as reference this answer comes from
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4674114/6656818